Electronic density of states from not the usual VASP outputs
In a very frustrating development, my VASP has decided to hang at the writing of outputs stage. While I troubleshoot that separately, for the moment I need to get an electronic density of states from either the vaspout.h5 or PROCAR output, not the more usual vasprun.xml or DOSCAR. This should be doable.
I have pymatgen and sumo, and the point of this question is parsing either of the above available files into something I can use for an electronic density of states. I do not care for the magnetic quantum number, but I do care about separating the DoS by $s$ vs $p$ vs $d$ orbitals for each element and atom.
So, starting condition: vaspout.h5 or PROCAR. K-points and bands are known. Number of atoms and their identities are known. K-point weighing factors are somewhere in the PROCAR and therefore gettable.
Possible final conditions:

a pymatgen density of states object
density of states dis-aggregated as above vs energy in some reasonably standard python format, e.g., numpy array or pandas.

(this is most likely a python question more than anything)
Can I get from this starting point to any one of the final ones, and if yes, then how?

I can't supply an answer directly, but this might be one of the few cases where if you can find the information in the file and explain to a LLM (ChatGPT4, llama3, etc.), it may be able to help you write a script really quickly to do this.  I have had good luck with this in the past.

Agreed, it's the finding part that is more annoying because who knows how VASP packages the data

Can you upload these files somewhere?  I suspect someone can do it all the same.
